# Command Line Menu in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a command line menu in C so that when the user enters a character, it will instantly process the character and carry out specific functions. The problem is, whenever I try to make it so that after each input is processed, the menu displays again and is ready for new input, the program will just continually read input and never process it unless I exit the program.

This is the code that works 1 time through:

```
char command;
    command = getchar();
    switch(command){
    case 'c':
        //create a new hash table;
        break;

    case 'l':
        //look up a word;
        break;

    case 'f':
        //read a file
        break;

    case 'p':
        //print the table;
        break;

    case 'r':
        //Remove a word
        break;

    case 'q':
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
```

However, if I try to place it into an infinite loop to continually run, like I said, it will never process the inputs until I exit the program.

Comment: You need a `default` case in your switch (with, eg, `printf("The char typed was '%c' (value %d).\n", command, command); break;`).

Comment: As far as I see there is no code that actually does anything.

Comment: did you press the "enter" key after each input character?

Comment: My C is a bit rusty, but after the call to getchar() run "while (((value = getchar()) != '\n') && (value != EOF));" to clear the buffer. The next call to getchar() should then wait for a new character to be entered. This is using VS2012. The "value" variable should be declared and used just by this loop.

Comment: Note that `getchar()` and relatives return an `int` and not a `char`. That's because they have to be able to return any valid `char` value plus a distinct value, EOF. Using `char` instead of `int` leads to one of two problems. If plain `char` is a signed type, then some valid character (often ÿ, y-umlaut, 0xFF, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) is mis-recognized as EFO. If plain `char` is an unsigned type, then the value assigned to the `char` variable is never recognized as EOF. Neither is really acceptable.

Comment: using enter does not throw a '\n' nor does it throw an EOF... so it's just stuck...

Also, chars are handled as ints, so it's fine the way I am using them. This program will never receive any symbols beyond the 26 English characters

Comment: A claim that 'enter does not throw a `'\n'`' is not readily believable.  What character does it generate?  If you want single-character inputs, you can find a ton of questions about getting single characters — as recently as today and as ancient as 4 years ago.  (And No, the way you have the code written, you have a problem with the type used for characters, whether you're willing to admit it or not!  You may not stress test it and therefore may not see the problem (especially if `char` is a signed type); but if other people were to use it, they would.)

Comment: I solved it. Not sure why this solution makes a difference... but I extracted the getchar and switch to it's own function, then in the main call the function in the loop and it works...

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you — it works for me.  Note the use of `int` for the variable `command`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int command;

    while ((command = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        switch(command)
        {
        case 'c':
            printf("Create a new hash table\n");
            break;

        case 'l':
            printf("Look up a word\n");
            break;

        case 'f':
            printf("Read a file\n");
            break;

        case 'p':
            printf("Print the table\n");
            break;

        case 'r':
            printf("Remove a word\n");
            break;

        case 'q':
            printf("Quit\n");
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Unexpected input %d (0x%.2X) ('%c')\n",
                   command, command, isgraph(command) ? command : '.');
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```